# SQL - Dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

Data is stored in the SQL database by month. For e.g. `TableA_202002`, `TableA_202001` and so on. The frontend user selects the required Month and Year which is passed on as a parameter into a stored procedure. There maybe other parameters passed in to the SP. In the SP a dynamic query is constructed by including the parameters.

```
SET @p_SQL = 'SELECT * FROM TABLEA_' + @p_TableName
EXEC (@p_SQL)
```

I wanted to know if there is a better way of getting the data than building dynamic queries. Thanks

Comment: Yes.  Don't store the same data across multiple tables to being with.  Fix your processing so the month is a *column* in the data rather than embedded in the table name.

Comment: And if you want to store each month separately, but still have one logical table, use a Partitioned Table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15